# How to create multipart request in dio?

Tags: flutter, dart

I used to send file to server by HTTP package like this:

```
final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', postUri);

      request.headers.addAll(Parameters.getHeader(User.accessToken!));

      request.files.add(multipartFile);
      final responseStream = await request.send();
```

but now I'm using Dio package as it gives us more tools, so I implemented it like this:

```
final multiPartFile = MultipartFile.fromBytes(
      result.fileContent!.readAsBytesSync(),
      filename: 'file',
    );

final result = await _httpClient.post<dynamic>(
      ApiEndPoint.fileUploadUrl,
      data: FormData.fromMap({'file': multiPartFile }),
    );
```

but I get 400 : Bad request, is anything wrong with dio? is any difference between sending file in dio and HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
     "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path, filename:fileName),
});

response = await dio.post("/info", data: formData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope that Flutter Dio Multipart request example below helps you

```
final formData = FormData.fromMap({
  'name': 'dio',
  'date': DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
  'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile('./text.txt', filename: 'upload.txt'),
  'files': [
    await MultipartFile.fromFile('./text1.txt', filename: 'text1.txt'),
    await MultipartFile.fromFile('./text2.txt', filename: 'text2.txt'),
  ]
});
final response = await dio.post('/info', data: formData);
```

Under **'files'** you can send single file or array of multiple file paths. In this, I have added 2 files which are static, you may update the code according to your requirement i.e. make upload files one by one or multiple files in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will helps you
final Dio dio = Dio();
dio.options.headers["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data";

String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;

FormData data = FormData.fromMap({`enter code here`
"file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
file.path,
filename: fileName,
),
});

final response = await dio.post('/info', data: formData);

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of multiplart

```
// url
String url = "url";

// form data encapsulation
var formData = FormData.fromMap({
  'other_string_data' : 'sample',
  'image': todo.filePath != null? await MultipartFile.fromFile(todo.filePath!) : null,
});

Dio dio = Dio();

// execute url
try {
  // success response
  Response response = await dio.post(url, data: formData,
      cancelToken: cancelToken);
  Map<String, dynamic> json = response.data;
  
} on DioError catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
  // error response
  print(e);
  throw message;
}
```